# Xamarin - iOS is always building same version

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a multi OS app in Xamarin Forms, for Android and iOS.
Everything's fine with android compilation and deploy, but it's not that easy on iOS.
Visual Studio still deploy the same version again and again, like it's stuck somewhere in past.
Is there a cache to clean somewhere? The iOS app is displaying labels which are no more in my code, so it's probably a cache issue.
I tryied to clean the whole solution, in vain.

I deploy on a macOS virtual machine, hosted with VMware workstation. VS and xcode are installed on it.

There is an example of same page displayed in ios and android..

[image]

Comment: Did you try to delete /bin & /obj directories in your solution and rebuild?

Comment: Tried before for iOS bin and obj, now deleted them from the all solution but still same result. Uninstalling it on emulated device doesn't help btw

Comment: I guess uninstalling the app on the simulator didn't help either?

Comment: Even when i try a version of iphone i never used before it deploy the same thing. So not simulator related i guess

Comment: I think i figured it out comparing iOS project settings, idk how i came to change them but setting back x86_64 in build architecture seemed to solve it

Comment: My colleagues and I notice the same problem from time to time but we're neither sure what causes it, nor how to solve it. My colleague swears that restarting Visual Studio helps. I'm not so sure about that :) What we do know is that 1) cleaning the solution directory (deleting bin & obj) does not help and 2) uninstalling the app does not help either.

Comment: Try to delete the caches in the mac at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` then build it again